# Adding Progress bar - Swift

Tags: swift, progress-bar

I want to add a Progress bar to a tableViewController.

I have one function called `HelpersFunctions` which do all the calculation.
The function `doCalculation` is responsible for the calculation.

So, I add the following notification to `doCalculation` as follow:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .return_progress, object: self)
for i in 1...n1 {
 //Do all the calculation
}
```

So, once I reach `NotificationCenter.default.post`, it will move to a Tableview Controller called `CreateNewElementVC`

now, inside the `ViewDidLoad`, I added the following line:

```
//progress
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showProgress), name: .return_progress, object: nil)
```

In the same swift file, I added the following:

```
let container_elementProperty: ProgressBarView = {
    let view = ProgressBarView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

    @objc func showProgress() {
    if(progressCounter > 1.0){timer.invalidate()}
    print("Step 1")
    container_elementProperty.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    container_elementProperty.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    container_elementProperty.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: .userInteractive)
    queue.async {
        print("Step 2")
        self.view.addSubview(self.container_elementProperty)

    }

    //view.addSubview(container_elementProperty)
    print("Step 3")
    container_elementProperty.progress = progressCounter
    progressCounter = progressCounter + progressIncrement

    let x1: Float = Float(start_Counting)
    let x2: Float = Float(End_Counting)

    let xx: Float = x1 / x2 * 100

    print("Start at: \(xx) %)")

}
```

So, first I put all the required data in the `CreateNewElementVC`, then there is a button called run to do all the calculation and then it will move to another `TableViewController` with all the result.

So while I am inside the function `doCalculation`, the progress bar should appear .

In fact, the Progress bar `container_elementProperty (UIview)` appeared just after the calculation is completed which make the progress bar is useless.

Any idea how to make the View called `container_elementProperty UIView` to be seen ?

I am close to solve this issue as I can see the progress in the stack as below image, I just want to show this on the screen before completing the calculation.

[image]

Why I am not able to put the view on the screen while doing the calculation as you can see that step 2 ran first.
The warning related to this issue is: `UIView.addSubview(_:) must be used from main thread only`.

**A Sample Project can be checked on this [link](https://github.com/XinLok007/progress) at github.
Appreciate any kind of support.**

Comment: Are you calling both of them in the main thread? Probably your calculation is taking place in the main thread and that's why the progress bar appears after your calcs are done. Moreover, for showing a progress in iOS you'd better use delegation method. You might find this helpful https://medium.com/journey-of-one-thousand-apps/tracking-download-progress-with-swift-c1a13f3f8c66

Comment: Is there a way to show the progress on the navigationItem.title?

Comment: Are you using a timer? It's up to you but I strongly recommend don't use this method. However, if you insist on doing it this way, instead of printing the value in the main queue set ```navigationItem.title``` with that value

Comment: I am trying to find any solution which show the progress on the screen. I tried the above example in your first comment, I understood it but I wasn't able to make it work on my application maybe cause I am not that expert in swift and also my case is little different. If I will be able to pop up a view  while doing the calculation and then able to write in this view, then my issue will be solved. When I tried to use main queue, it didn't not work as expected.

Comment: if you can create a new project and share that piece of your code you need help with, i might be able to take a look at it.

Comment: Please have a look on the git file https://github.com/XinLok007/progress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/maysamsh/swift-circular-loader and I post some tips as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To simulate a progress, such as a network request you cannot simply do a `for` loop in the main thread, you should use `GCD`.
- To update the progress of an ongoing action use [Delegation](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift), not [KVO](https://hackernoon.com/kvo-kvc-in-swift-12f77300c387?gi=b7c2df129428).
- Using global variables makes your code flawed, avoid it!

This is a [working version](https://github.com/maysamsh/swift-circular-loader) of your code.

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for this piece of code, it is totally new for me. But I have no idea where I must include the calculations? This line  for i in 1...Int(End_C) { start_C = Float(i); percentage = start_C / End_C } was removed from the previous sample project ? how can I control the progress? Where I must include this piece of line?

Comment: Well, I don't know where do you get that number, but all you need is calling ```delegate.update(progress:)```. in this code: ```_delegate.update(progress: _counter)```, replace ```_counter``` with your number.

Comment: Yes, I understood the code. It is very helpfull. I will work on to apply it to my code. Thanks a lot man for your support.

Comment: By the way, it worked very well and as expected. thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend you watching https://itunes.apple.com/cn/course/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1309275316

Answer (score 0):

```
# Write By Tushar on 11/02/2021#

    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let totalValue:Float = 80.0
    var firstNumber:Int? = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progressBar.trackTintColor = .white
        progressBar.tintColor = .red
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    }
    func setProgress(firstValue:Float){
       let processValue = firstValue/totalValue
        progressBar.setProgress(processValue, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func btnResetClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
         print("Reset Button Clicked")
        firstNumber = 0
         progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    }
    @IBAction func btnShowProgressClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

      
        guard let presentValue = firstNumber else { return }

        let newValue = presentValue + 1
        firstNumber = newValue
        setProgress(firstValue: Float(firstNumber!))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code snippet answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer more useful for future readers.